# A question about a chat room that is hosted by another SE

Tags: support, chat

If we visit chat now, we are shown three rooms https://chat.stackexchange.com/?tab=site&host=hinduism.stackexchange.com.

Of which, this room (https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/136751/room-for-johny-man-and-the-z) emerged from a post on Islam.SE. Then why is it being shown to users of Hinduism.SE too?

Does it have something to do with user Johny man's (https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/users/19288/johny-man) chat settings? Johny man is a member of Hinduism.SE and Islam.SE both.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The chat room didn't "emerge from a post" in the sense that it was created by someone moving comments to chat or something like that. It was created manually by a user going to chat and creating a chat room. As part of that process, they are given the opportunity to pick which site the room is parented on. It seems that the creator either didn't notice it was on Hinduism instead of Islam or opted to parent the room here.

You'd have to ask them which it is.